# A remark on the graph of a Brownian Motion according to the Law of the Iterated Logarithm

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

How from the Law of the Iterated Logarithm for the Brownian Motion

> For a standard Brownian motion $B$, we have $P(\limsup_{t->0^+}
>  \frac{B_t}{\sqrt{2t\log \log t^{-1}}}=1)=1$

do we get the following? $h(t)=\sqrt{2t\log \log t^{-1}}$

[image]

I get that $\limsup A_n$ is equivalent to $A_n$ i.o., but this relation is just for a sequence of sets, not a sequence of real numbers...

Comment: Assuming that h(t) is the expression in the LIL, this is essentially the definition of the limsup. The statement for the negatives follows from the reflection principle.

Comment: @MikeHawk Thanks for the comment. I understand that the $\limsup A_n$ is equivalent to $A_n$ i.o. , but this is only for a sequence of sets... In this case we have a sequence of real numbers.

Comment: The remark follows from the simple consequence of the result you recalled, that $$P\left(\limsup_{t\to0^+}
 \frac{B_t}{\sqrt{h(t)}}=1,\liminf_{t\to0^+}
 \frac{B_t}{\sqrt{h(t)}}=-1\right)=1$$ and even, from the weaker result that $$P\left(\limsup_{t\to0^+}
 \frac{B_t}{\sqrt{h(t)}}>0>\liminf_{t\to0^+}
 \frac{B_t}{\sqrt{h(t)}}\right)=1$$